# How to create a drawable right animation button

Tags: android, android-animation, drawable

How do I create a right spinning button animation, I tried below code but it kept crashing.

**button_spin_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
```

**Usage**

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        account_login.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_spin_animation), null);
        Drawable[] sb = account_login.getCompoundDrawables();
        AnimationDrawable animDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) sb[0];
        animDrawable.start();
    }
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.android.buyer/com.app.android.buyer.Login}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.app.android.buyer:drawable/button_spin_animation with resource ID #0x7f080146
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/button_spin_animation.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080146
        at 
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8: <rotate> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable.verifyRequiredAttributes(RotateDrawable.java:106)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable.inflate(RotateDrawable.java:76)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:145)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
        at
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded a solution for you. The `MainActivity.java` class contains 2 functions that will run the animation and also stop it. Take a look here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ImageView ImageIcon;
    public static boolean aBoolean = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageIcon = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(!aBoolean) {
                runBtnAnimation();
                aBoolean = true;
            }
            else {
                stopBtnAnimation();
                aBoolean = false;
            }
        });
        
    }

    private void runBtnAnimation() {
        ImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_flutter_dash_24);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.rotation_animation);
        ImageIcon.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

    private void stopBtnAnimation() {
        ImageIcon.clearAnimation();
        ImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_flutter_dash_24);
    }
}
```

After that you are going to create the `activity_main.xml` layout. I want to point out that you need to put the `Button` and the `ImageView` above each other with different `elevation` level, into a `frame` (here `FrameLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_flutter_dash_24"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The final part is to configure the animation behaviour in your `rotation_animation.xml` located into your `res/anim` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="359"/>
</set>
```

**RESULT**

[image: Image rotating in Button]

In this example the `ImageView` will rotate `infinite` after being clicked. The animation is stopping after another click and `set` it's previous `ImageResource`. But you can use the `function` `runBtnAnimation()` and `stopBtnAnimation()` as you like to. Cheers!

Comment: Am trying to spin button drawable right image not the the button, and also I will like it to keep spinning till I call ` anim.cancel();`

Comment: I updated my answer with the behaviour you are looking for :) Cheers!

Comment: Can you confirm that the answer was correct, in terms of knowing you need further help? And for me in improving solving question, is something missing? Would be glad about a bit feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 3 changes:

1. add drawable to your `button_spin_animation`
2. Use 2nd index if you want to get the right drawable.
3. Use `ObjectAnimator` to animate your drawable.

Following is example for your use case:

`Java file:`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                null,
                null,
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_spin_animation),
                null
        );

        int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;

        Drawable[] sb = tv.getCompoundDrawables();

        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(sb[2], "level", 0, MAX_LEVEL);
        anim.start();

    }

}
```

`button_spin_animation.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Replace `ic_add` with your drawable:

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used your example, replaced `ic_add ` with an image, it shows the image at right side of my button but it doesn't rotate.

Comment: @Peter you want to keep rotating it infinite times or you want to rotate it for some fixed time? Because my current implementation is very quick. It rotates & goes back to original position.  You can set `anim.setDuration(10000);`  to see the effect.